# Is there or can there be a way to highlight text in an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have asked a question which has yielded a massive list-type answer.

There are several points within this answer that I would like more information about, but placing them all into a comment (which might not even fit) would be really messy / illegible and if someone did this to my answer I probably wouldn't even respond.

Could there be a feature where I as the OP can highlight parts of the answer which will notify the answerer, giving them the option to provide more information about what I've highlighted? The highlights could be yellow but only visible to the answerer (so that while browsing the website there isn't yellow everywhere).

This would be particularly useful for this style of answer, especially because I'd like information on 5 or more of those points.

Comment: Instant workaround: post a comment in that answer with a link to this very question. The answerer might tolerate a jump to meta and follow up.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi True, true.

Comment: I assume your question was about this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380789/what-are-the-major-performance-hitters-in-as3-aside-from-rendering-vectors Which is really Too-Broad, hence there is this rediculously long answer. Clearly a case of the X-Y problem.

Comment: @Luuklag thank you for going on a treasure hunt through my question history and your insightful feedback on a nine year old thread.

Comment: You're welcome Marty. You can thank an editor for putting your question on the frontpage ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [a browser extension such as Diigo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oojbgadfejifecebmdnhhkbhdjaphole).

[image: Highlighted]

Then share it in a comment like this

> I highlighted some things that I need clarification on http://diigo.com/0lovo

This works similar to how users within the JavaScript tag use [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)

<sub>Plug: Web Apps Moderator: SE site for end users of web applications</sub>

Comment: While this would work for the "massive list-type answer" example from the question, I would not like it when folks start using that on these sites. I'd expect the question asker put some effort in the communication instead. Also, Diigo works with cached versions, which to me does not seem to work well with the continuous editing we see on these sites. (That said: nice extension.)